# Combining a BubbleChart with a MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts, plot-themes

Is there a way I can combine a `BubbleChart` with a `MatrixPlot`? I already plotted a `MatrixPlot` of dimension 7x5. I also made a `BubbleChart` of the same dimension. I tried to combine the two plots using `Show` but I didn't work. I just want to combine both in such a way that each bubble is placed in its respective cell in the `MatrixPlot`. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you are using so we can understand exactly what plots you are trying to combine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
mtx = ArrayReshape[Range[35], {7, 5}];

{w,h} = Dimensions@mtx;
coords = Reverse@Transpose@CoordinateBoundsArray[{{1,h},{1,w}},1]-.5;
bubbs = Flatten[MapThread[Append,{coords,mtx},2],1];
Show[
 MatrixPlot[mtx, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"],
 BubbleChart[bubbs, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
]
```

[image: bubbles on a matrix plot]

Comment: Thank you so much flinty for your help. Much appreciated....